# Why do build drafts not merge/notify about merge conflicts on draft publishing?

Tags: tfs, merge, build, azure-devops

Assume the following build

1. Powershell Task `Write-Host 'Original1';`

We create the following draft

1. Powershell Task `Write-Host 'Original1';Write-Host 'Draft2';`

At the same time we had to change the original build - set `Continue on Error`, for example, and a new `Timeout` value.

Then we publish the draft. The original build would become

1. Powershell Task `Write-Host 'Original1';Write-Host 'Draft2';`

But both `Continue on Error` and `Timeout` would be overwritten with the values from the draft (original values at the time the draft had been created).

Perhaps I am missing something in my understanding how drafts should work (there is basically nothing about them on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/), or perhaps it is even a genuine defect in the TFS version we use (2018.2), but I'd have expected either a proper merge or at least some message preventing one from overwriting the changes in the original build.

Otherwise drafts just seem to be of very limited and error-prone use.

Am I missing something?

*P.S.: Tried different combinations of changes on multiple tasks and etc. In some cases(when modifying inline powershell in the same task) drafts got "published" (as deleted), but no changes at all made their way to the original build (not even a new history entry), so I am much more inclined to think that the entire drafts feature is a bit defective as of now*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have contacted Microsoft and as of now (end of 2018) the current behaviour is considered to be by design

> As it turns out, as of now this is the intended way for it work. The
>   Draft option just exists so that you can first test a definition
>   before committing it.

So, until something changes, the Drafts feature should be used carefully in any environments where concurrent changes to(drafts of) builds/task groups/releases can be made.